# C# Linq Group by Object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have an issue of using group by in LINQ to SQL statement.

The cod I have is

```
var combinedItems = (from article in articles
                     join author in authors
                     on article.AuthorId equals author.Id into tempAuthors
                     from tempAuthor in tempAuthors.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new { article , author = tempAuthor});

var groups1 = (from combinedItem in combinedItems
               group combinedItem by combinedItem.article into g
               select g.Key).ToList();

var groups2 = (from combinedItem in combinedItems
               group combinedItem by combinedItem.article.Id into g
               select g.Key).ToList();
```

I tried to group in two different ways. The first way, I group by an object and the second way I just group by a field in one of the objects.

When I run `groups1`, I got an error saying need to evaluate in client side, while when I use `groups2`, it works all good. Can I ask what could be wrong? If I want to group by object, is there any way to do it?

Comment: i think you can't group directly by object,but if you build an anonymous object based on all properties of the initial object, will work, like:``group combinedItem by new{combinedItem.article.Id,combinedItem.article.Name,...} into g``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want to group by object, as you've not overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode()` in your `Article` class or implemented [`IEqualityComparer<Article>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) you're just getting the default comparison, which checks if the references are equal. So what you need is something like this:

```
class GroupItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Article>
{

    public bool Equals(Article x, Article y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id &&
            x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Article obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode() ^
            obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then you need to change your query to lambda expression:

```
var groups1 = combinedItems.GroupBy(c => c.article , new GroupItemComparer())
                           .Select(c => c.Key).ToList();
```

In case you got any exception regarding translation your method to SQL, you can use `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` methods before your `GroupBy` method, with this methods after data is loaded, any further operation is performed using Linq to Objects, on the data already in memory.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the `GroupBy` is using  *reference equality* by default, and you could get around it by specifying one or more *properties* to group by.  But **why is that an error**?

The whole point of the query is to translate your Linq query into SQL. Since object reference equality on the client can't be easily translated to SQL, the translator doesn't support it and gives you an error.

When you provide one or more *properties* to group by, the provider *can* translate that to SQL (e.g. `GROUP BY article.Id`), and thus the second method works without error.